# WMD editor is not working on facebook? Editor doesn't show when called from an iframe

Tags: php, facebook, markdown, wmd

This one works http://www.exootlab.com/ivolgina/test2.php and this one http://apps.facebook.com/ivolgina/test2.php doesnt! Does anyone know how to fix this?‎ Editor doesn't show when called from an iframe.

PS: Both are same page, one loaded in FB canvas, and the other is not

Answer (score 0):

I just saw another WMD question that mentioned another fork, [available here](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/wmd). In the changes section it notes:

> Removed top level frame pollution, forcing WMD to run only in its own document.

So give that a try, it may solve your problem.